# Window Store App: Grid animation from code behind?

Tags: c#, grid, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

In my XAML file there is a Grid:
`

```
<Grid x:Name="mainGrid" Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" >
</Grid>
```

`

Let's say that, it contains many objects - images, text, etc.
The question is - how to animate this grid (position) using only code behind?

Comment: Why was this question closed as "unclear"??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple `Sliding animation`

**XAML part**

```
<Grid x:Name="Gridg"  Height="200" Width="200" >
  <Grid.RenderTransform>
       <CompositeTransform ></CompositeTransform>
   </Grid.RenderTransform>
</Grid>
```

**Code Behind:** On any button click event

```
private void StartAnimation(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Storyboard moveSb=new Storyboard();
  TranslateTransform moveTransform = new TranslateTransform();
  Gridg.RenderTransform = moveTransform;
  Duration duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
  DoubleAnimation myDoubleAnimationX = new DoubleAnimation();
  myDoubleAnimationX.Duration = duration;
  myDoubleAnimationX.To = 200;
  moveSb.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimationX);
  Storyboard.SetTarget(myDoubleAnimationX, moveTransform);
  Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimationX, "X");
  moveSb.Begin();
}
```

For detailed information please see this [Storyboard Animation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.storyboard)